# Meaning of "as the Bucks fall to the Suns"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, headlinese

the headline is:

> A star’s return is not enough as the Bucks fall to the Suns ([nytimes.com](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/07/07/sports/basketball/giannis-antetokounmpo-nba-finals.html))

I can't seem to be able of interpret ***the Bucks fall to the Suns*** part

Comment: This isn't a question about *English*. It's just about knowing the names of American baseball teams.

Answer (score 3):

The correct transcription would be 'the Bucks fall to the Suns'. The Bucks and Suns are shortened proper nouns (names of basketball teams). An American basketball player, Giannis Antetokounmpo, returned to his team, the Milwaukee **Bucks**, after having been injured in a game. He played in a game against another team, the Phoenix **Suns**, but his presence was not enough to save the Bucks from defeat by (from falling to) the Suns. Team names are often shortened in this way (city or locale name removed) in sports stories,especially in  headlines, if it is likely that readers will be familiar with the team. They may also be shortened within a story after being shown in full once.